# While mobile redirection there is issue of cache of drupal cache

Tags: caching, mobile, drupal-7

Step taken : Site on Drupal7 both desktop and mobile.
In case of mobile redirection drupal cache issue generated every time, whenever i open my site in mobile it shows desktop url ie. (**www.example.com**) but in actual it should be (**m.example.com** ).

I have taken some needed step every-time i have to clear Drupal cache from my desktop, then only m able to see the redirection else it shows the desktop version.

Another issue once desktop Drupal cache generated mobile redirection is not working.

Please help!!

Comment: There is a conflict somewhere. Try to see loading time with/without cache, if it's not heavy, disable cache.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try any one (Fusion Mobile) [mobile theme](https://drupal.org/project/fusion_mobile) with [themekey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module?